# C# read USB Descriptor

Tags: c#, usb, libusb, usb-descriptor

How can I read the USB Descriptor by C#? I found `LibUSB.NET` but I can't get USB devices like in examples:

```
UsbRegDeviceList allDevices = UsbDevice.AllDevices;
```

it returns count = 0

Comment: show us what you are doing please..

Comment: that row it returns count value = 0, show I can't go continue, I want to list USB devices which have connected to pc, when I read the documentation of libUSB.NET, that row's just retrieve a list lib-win32 and win32 usb